# Лимит сообщений для бота Вконтакте

Tags: python

Во Вконтакте ограничение на ботов, они не могут отправлять более 100 сообщений за 15 минут одному пользователю, иначе бот ломается, с помощью try ... except это не исправить. Я решил ввести переменную и присвоить ей ноль, также ввел вторую переменную, которая отсчитывает 15 минут и обнуляет первую переменную, если за 15 минут не превысился лимит, его я установил в 85 сообщений. Если набирается лимит в 85 сообщений, то пользователю вылезает сообщение о превышении лимита и действие программы приостанавливается на 15 минут. Но потом я узнал, что в переменную добавляются все сообщения всех пользователей. Мне нужно, чтобы переменная limit относилась к каждому пользователю отдельно.

```
limit = 0
timeout = time.time() + 60 * 15
for event in longpoll.listen():

    # Если пришло новое сообщение
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
        if event.to_me:

            # Сообщение от пользователя
            request = event.text
            limit += 1
            if limit > 85:
              write_msg(event.user_id, 'Вы превысили количество сообщений боту. Повторите попытку через 15 минут.')
              time.sleep(900)
            if time.time() > timeout:
              limit = 0
              timeout = time.time() + 60 * 15
```

Comment: Заведите словарь вида {user_id: limit}

Comment: `if limit > 85: time.sleep(900)` - при такой логике Ваш бот перестанет отвечать *всем*, если хотя бы 1 человек его "зафлудит".

Comment: Да, я уже понял, а как можно еще сделать лимит?

Comment: Вам уже уже ответили. Заведите словарь вида user_id : limit. Чем вас не устраивает это решение? Вам не нужно делать sleep, вам нужно увеличивать значение "limit" в словаре у каждого пользователя, когда тот отправляет сообщение и делать проверку, если значение в словаре > 85, то "Вы превысили количество сообщений боту . Повторите попытку через 15 минут.", и тут же ставите задачу на обнуление значение словаря для id текущего пользователя через 15 минут. Перед каждым сообщением нужно получать id пользователя "вконтакте", сверять со словарем, есть ли уже такой id, если нет - добавлять.

Comment: {vk_id : message_count}, если вам будет понятнее.

Comment: Вообще, в идеале, нужно проверять каждые 15 минут, не менялось ли значение в словаре для каждого пользователя и, если не менялось, то обнулять значение в словаре.

Comment: Спасибо, но я написал новый алгоритм, если он не будет нормально работать, то обращусь к вашему, а пока что мой работает без ошибок

Comment: Ок. Так же, что бы бот не отсылал новых сообщений при превышении лимита, всю вашу логику отправки сообщений для конкретного пользователя разумно выполнять в цикле:
a = {"131234": 30, "14124124": 40}

Comment: while a["id текущего пользователя"] <= 85:(поправил синтаксис, освежил свою память:))

Comment: Я бы написал декоратор. Лимит и временные метки хранил бы в словаре, как Вам подсказали выше.